# Parametrization of hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that there are similar questions to this on stackexchange, but I really don't understand the answers/explanations there.

How would you parametrize an equation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by the equation
$$
2x + y + z + 3t = 5.
$$
Can I just assume y, z, and t are free variables and write...

$$
\begin{split}
x &= (5-p-q-3r)/2\\
y &=p\\
z &=q\\
t &=r
\end{split}
$$

or is this not correct? If not correct then why is it not?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct. What do you want it for?

Comment: Hm, it's a question from my textbook but I was wondering if I can always just assume that y,z,t are free variables and show x in terms of y,z,t.